# Guava - Filter by Property and Contains

Tags: java, collections, filter, guava

I am trying to filter by multiple properties in an object, a CarObj in my case:

```
    List<String> colorList = (List<String>)filterCriteria.get("Color");
    List<String> makeList = (List<String>)filterCriteria.get("Make");
    List<String> rimSizeList = (List<String>)filterCriteria.get("RimSize");

    Predicate<String> predColor = Predicates.in(ImmutableSet.copyOf(colorList));
    Predicate<CarObj> predColor2 = Predicates.compose(predColor ,[????] );

    Predicate<String> predMakeList  = Predicates.in(ImmutableSet.copyOf(makeList));
    Predicate<CarObj> predMakeList2 = Predicates.compose(predMakeList, [????] );

    Predicate<String> predRimSize = Predicates.in(ImmutableSet.copyOf(rimSizeList));
    Predicate<CarObj> predRimSize2 = Predicates.compose(predRimSize, [????] );

    Collection<CarObj> filtered = FluentIterable.from(mAllCars)
            .filter(predColor2)
            .filter(predMakeList2)
            .filter(predRimSize2)
            .toList();
```

How do I put in logic to handle StartsWith or Contains functionality? 
So, if a user types in "Silver" and in my Collection of CarObjs the Model property has "Silverado", "Silverline", "Silverpig", "Tacoma", "Accord", etc...

I want to find a way to filter so it returns cars that begin with the "Silver". It would return all cars that are of model Silverado, Silverline, or Silverpig that meets the other 3 filters, Color, Rim Size, and Make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8, you could just write

```
Predicate<CarObj> predColor2 = Predicates.compose(predColor , CarObj::getColor);
```

but otherwise you'll have to write

```
Predicate<CarObj> predColor2 = Predicates.compose(predColor , 
   new Function<CarObj, String>() {
     @Override public String apply(CarObj car) {
       return car.getColor();
     }
   });
```

If you want to filter by e.g. `startsWith`, then don't use `Predicates.compose`, but instead write

```
final Set<String> makes = ImmutableSet.copyOf(makeList);
Predicate<CarObj> predMake2 = new Predicate<CarObj>() {
  @Override public boolean apply(CarObj car) {
    for (String make : makes) {
      if (car.getMake().startsWith(make)) {
        return true;
      }
    } 
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: I am not sure this answers my question as I am able to filter by property (color, make, rim size), but I am trying how to also filter by Contains or Starts with for the `Model` property of a `CarObj`